# c#.net convert object properties to list

Tags: .net, json

I have a class like below and set the values as json by calling api

```
public class GroupSettings
    {       
        [JsonProperty("whoCanJoin")] public string WhoCanJoin { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("whoCanViewMembership")] public string WhoCanViewMembership { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("whoCanViewGroup")] public string WhoCanViewGroup { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("whoCanModerateMembers")] public string WhoCanModerateMembers { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("allowExternalMembers")] public string AllowExternalMembers { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("whoCanPostMessage")] public string WhoCanPostMessage { get; set; }           
}
```

json look like this

```
GroupSettings groupsetting = 
    "{\n \"whoCanJoin\": \"INVITED_CAN_JOIN\",
    \n \"whoCanViewMembership\": \"ALL_MANAGERS_CAN_VIEW\",
    \n \"whoCanViewGroup\": \"ALL_MEMBERS_CAN_VIEW\",
    \n \"whoCanModerateMembers\": \"OWNERS_AND_MANAGERS\",
    \n \"allowExternalMembers\": \"false\",
    \n \"whoCanPostMessage\": \"ALL_MANAGERS_CAN_POST\"\n}\n"
```

I want to convert GroupSettings properties in to list of object

```
public class GroupSettingNew
    {       
        [JsonProperty("Setting")] public string  Setting { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("SettingValue")] public string SettingValue { get; set; }       
    }
```

Final output like this

```
List<GroupSettingNew> test=
    "[{""Setting"":""whoCanJoin"",""SettingValue"":""INVITED_CAN_JOIN"",}]",
    "[{""Setting"":""whoCanViewMembership"",""SettingValue"":""ALL_MANAGERS_CAN_VIEW"",}]",
    "[{""Setting"":""whoCanViewGroup"",""SettingValue"":""ALL_MEMBERS_CAN_VIEW"",}]",
    "[{""Setting"":""whoCanModerateMembers"",""SettingValue"":""OWNERS_AND_MANAGERS"",}]",
    "[{""Setting"":""allowExternalMembers"",""SettingValue"":""false"",}]",
    "[{""Setting"":""whoCanPostMessage"",""SettingValue"":""ALL_MANAGERS_CAN_POST"",}]"
```

any one please help would be appreciated

Comment: You have to show some effort of your own.  We aren't here to write code for you.  Please read [ask] and consider modifying your question.

Comment: Tip: `typeof(GroupSettings).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);`

Answer (score 0):

Please use Jsonconvert -> Serialization to convert json object to List.

```
 List<object> myDeserializedObjList = (List<object>)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseContent, typeof(List<object>));
```

'responseContent' is string data type of json results